# MassTransit ISendEndpoint.Send method doesn't throw exception when RabbitMQ is unreachable

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

Having the following code snippet:

```
try 
{
  UpdateCommand updateCommand = new UpdateCommand
  {
    Name = "Update" 
  };

  await sendEndpoint.Send(updateCommand);
} 
catch (BrokerUnreachableException ex) 
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

When calling Send method and when there is no connection with RabbitMQ then exception is not being thrown. Is it supposed to work like this ?

I've tried to ConnectSendObserver to my ReceiveEndpoint like so:

```
ISendObserver sendObserver = new UpdateSendObserver();
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(EventBusConstants.UpdateQueue, c => {
  c.ConfigureConsumer<UpdateCommandConsumer> (ctx);
  cfg.ConnectSendObserver(sendObserver);
});
```

But it doesn't hit any of the PreSend, PostSend, SendFault methods when there is no connection with RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained in the GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/2531), you can cancel the call to `Send`/`Publish` using a `CancellationToken`. The transport uses a retry policy if a connection to the broker is not available.